# How to sanitize for String filePath to download the file from S3bukcet for Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, checkmarx

Following error received:

> The application's downloadObject method executes an SQL query with
> key, at **key(filePath)** of
> src\main\java\com\sample\service\S3Service.java. The application
> constructs this SQL query by embedding an untrusted string into the
> query without proper sanitization. The concatenated string is
> submitted to the database, where it is parsed and executed
> accordingly.
>
> An attacker would be able to inject arbitrary syntax and data into the
> SQL query, by crafting a malicious payload and providing it via the
> input filePath; this input is then read by the downloadFile method at
> **(@RequestParam String filePath)** of src\main\java\com\sample\controller\S3Controller.java. This input then
> flows through the code, into a query and to the database server -
> without sanitization. This may enable an SQL Injection attack.

Sample code:
Controller:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/download/{id}")
public ResponseEntity downloadFile(
        @PathVariable Integer id,
        @RequestParam String filePath) {
    s3Service.downloadObject(filePath);
}
```

Service:

```java
public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadObject(String filePath) {
      GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
          GetObjectRequest.builder()
              .bucket("bucketName reading from propeties")
              .key(filePath)
              .build();
}
```

How to pass Checkmarx?

Comment: This looks like a false-positive to me. Report it as a bug to Checkmarx. There is no potential for SQL injection here (unless in your real code you're doing something else than what you show here)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel,  after I  got the filePath from controller am adding some concatenation  to specify the exact s3bucket file location. Other than this am not doing in my code

Comment: It is possible that is what triggers the warning. You may want to provide a [mre].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, you mean to say that  because of my concatenation to filePath triggers the warning?

Comment: I guess, I'm not sure if it applies to S3 paths, but there is a class of vulnerabilities called [path traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal). maybe Checkmarx fires on that (though then I'm not sure why it triggers a warning about SQL). In any case, without a [mre] no one will be able to try it out to know for sure. Alternatively, you should contact Checkmarx support.